# Error in custom database built with Kraken2

Tags: database, build, taxonomy

I need to do some classifications with kraken2 for my master thesis. In order to do that, I need to build a custom db with this software.

In this db I need bacteria and fungi, for example.

I followed the steps in the documentation. I started downloading the taxonomy and adding the libraries as follow:

```
kraken2-build --download-taxonomy --db $DBNAME
kraken2-build --download-library bacteria --db $DBNAME
kraken2-build --download-library fungi --db $DBNAME
```

After I built my db using the following line:

```
kraken2-build --build --db $DBNAME
```

Eventually, I obtained an empty db, because if I do the inspect on it, the table size is equal to zero.

I also found another way in a github thread. If I add the flag "--no-masking" to the libraries, I have no errors. Actually, I do not think that this approach is the best one. So I need an help to resolve the problem.

Tell me if you need more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add genomes ?
I mean you download your necessary genomes from NCBI refernce genomes and then you add them.